# vAxis Values not visible in bar chart : Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, dom-events, google-fusion-tables

My values in the  vertical axis are not visible as shown in the image:

[image].

What could be the problem with my code?

```
      function drawVisualization() {
    google.visualization.drawChart({
      containerId: 'visualization',
      dataSourceUrl: 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=',
      query: 'SELECT Environment, GirlPupils, BoyPupils, FemaleTeachers, MaleTeachers FROM 1eC4sIAgVXfFj01mOM2cDiyW2nly7TcFeIXj1G3s',
      chartType: 'BarChart',
      options: {
        title: 'Number of Students and Teachers',
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Environment'
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Number'
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

As I can tell from the image the vertical values is *actually* shown! The issues is

1. You have a very little height set for the chart-container, trying to show a *lot* of bars
2. The fontSize for vAxis is to the opposit relatively large
3. There can often be problems with lack of space to the left

Change the height of the `<div>`-container to something that actually can hold the many bars :

```
<div id="visualization" style="height:1000px;"></div>
```

Change fontSize for the vAxis and add some space to the left by chartArea

```
options: {
   title: 'Number of Students and Teachers',
   vAxis: {
      title: 'Environment',
      textStyle : { fontSize : 7 }
   },
      hAxis: {
      title: 'Number'
   },
   chartArea: {left: "150",top: 0 }
}
```

[image]

---

### Edit :

In order to only select columns where `Environment` is Rural, Urban or Peri Urban, change your query to

```sql
SELECT Environment, GirlPupils, BoyPupils, FemaleTeachers, MaleTeachers 
FROM 1eC4sIAgVXfFj01mOM2cDiyW2nly7TcFeIXj1G3s 
WHERE Environment IN ('Rural', 'Urban','Peri Urban')
```

note that normal SQL syntax `OR` is not supported by FusionTables, you must use `IN`. Also strings must be in single quotes `''`.

Comment: And might you know why my values (Environment) are repeating themselves?

I want only three values to appear:Rural,Urban and Peri Urban?

Comment: This is my query..

query: "SELECT Environment,'BoyPupils','GirlPupils','FemaleTeachers','MaleTeachers','BoardingPupils' " +
              "FROM 1eC4sIAgVXfFj01mOM2cDiyW2nly7TcFeIXj1G3s
              WHERE Environment IN('Rural','Urban','Peri Urban')",

but its still not working! Could it be a case with my tables?